# Rewrite URL's only in PHP

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have the following problem. I would like to use my new TYPO3 (version 9). Unfortunately, there is no RealURL for this version.
I looked at the RealURL configuration and put my URL parameters in an array. These are normally used by RealURL and output with the associated value.
Can I somehow manage this in PHP as well? Possibly write a function and put in an array all URL parameters (which are many) and then outputs me instead of the parameter the corresponding name?

That's what RealURL looked like

```
'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                // Kufer GetVars start
                'OUTPUT1' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'GET_PARAM1',
                    ),
                ),
                'OUTPUT2' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'GET_PARAM2',
                    ),
                ),
                'OUTPUT3' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'GET_PARAM3',
                        'valueMap' => array(
                            'OUTPUT4' => GET_PARAM4,
                            'OUTPUT5' => GET_PARAM5,
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The concept of routing changed completely with version 9. The concepts of EXT:realurl don't apply anymore.

Please take a look at the new routing docs, e.g. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html

Comment: I have read the documentation. But I'm stuck with the .yaml files. Because there are many parameters and some of them are not output in the same order.

Sometimes like this: domain.de/index.php?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3

And sometimes like this: domain.de/index.php?param1=1&param3=3&param2=2

I would then have to write a configuration for every possible link issue. That seems to me to be very much code.